# How best to manipulate module state javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to figure how best, and in as functional manner as possible one should manipulate module state outside of that module.

My current (simplified) code:

```js
// cache.js
const cache = {};

const addToCache = (key, item) => {
  cache[key] = item;
}

export default addToCache;
```

Is there a more functional way to create some data structure which needs to be manipulated in various parts of the codebase?

Comment: "functional" and "state of module" don't really fit together.

Comment: Agree! this is sort of my question, some state must be managed so how best to do so in as "functional" manner as possible.

Comment: There is no proper answer to this general question. You can avoid a lot of state by just calling new functions when you need new values, either non-recursively or recursivley. If this isn't enough you can compose functions that return a tuple containing the result and a state field. You can abstract from such functions by using a state monad. However, in all these cases we talk about state that is passed along compositions. Global state should be avoided anyway.

Comment: Hi @bob could you give an example please?

Comment: I have a [chapter on state](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum/blob/master/ch-2.md) in my FP course, which attempts to illustrate the big picture. Maybe you can apply some of it to your issue. If you are interested in caching specifically, you should also take a look at memoization. Caching in FP requires lazyness, i.e. it is hard to accomplish in JS.

Comment: Looks great thanks @bob!

Answer (score -2):

Well, the best solution is a singleton class: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

One of the best solution that I can recommend you is next:

```
class UserStore {
  constructor(){
   if(! UserStore.instance){
     this._data = [];
     UserStore.instance = this;
   }

   return UserStore.instance;
  }

 add(item){
   this._data.push(item);
  }

 get(id){
   return this._data.find(d => d.id === id);
 }
}

const instance = new UserStore();
Object.freeze(instance);
```

It's not my solution actually, I found it when I tried to make my own solution, but the solution above is the best. You can read more by next article: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/

Comment: This is far more complicated than the code of the OP. Why do you consider this "*the best solution*"?